# Equally as acceptable?

Tags: grammar

I was reading [an article in *The Atlantic*](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2011/10/once-and-all-its-spelled-protester-not-protestor/334452/) when I ran across this sentence:

> Are both spellings equally as acceptable?

I've seen this "equally as" construction before, and I've wondered if it was acceptable. To me

> Are both spellings equally acceptable?

is a perfectly grammatical and complete sentence, and the version with "equally as" sounds wrong. How does it even make sense? If two things are not equally "as acceptable", does that mean that one is more "as acceptable" than the other?

Anyway, even if there's nothing *wrong* with "equally as", isn't the "as" redundant? Is there any difference in meaning between the two versions?

Comment: What are you asking? The verb [*protest*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protestor) can form the nouns **protester** and **protestor**: "protester or protestor \ prə-​ˈte-​stər, ˈprō-​ˌte-​ , prō-​ˈte-​ \ noun". Both spellings are in the dictionary, although the far more common spelling is the first. But I don't see how "the correct spelling" of ***that*** word could be either *riotor* (which is not in the dictionary, although *rioter* is) or *lootor* (which is also not in the dictionary, although *looter* is).

Comment: On about my tenth reading of the question, it seems that the confusion of the introductory paragraph is a red herring to your actual question. If word A is used twice as commonly as word B, it could be said that word A is twice as acceptable as word B. (It's accepted twice as often.) So, *equally as acceptable* makes sense to me.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm sorry, I had no idea I was being so obscure. I hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: Ah! Yes, things are much clearer now.

Comment: (I can't quite figure out how to express that as a complete answer, so I'm leaving it as a comment for now. It might also prompt you to rethink the specifics of your question.)

Comment: @JasonBassford - The rioter/looter point was political/social commentary (and/or humour), not really part of the question.

Comment: @JasonBassford As a complete sentence, I regard _Both spellings are equally acceptable_ as the correct version. (The acceptability of both is equivalent.)

Comment: Just a guess from the two first search results of 'equally as': (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equally%20as) and (https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_e&page=91iP01J6Pj8I.html) , merging 'equally' with 'just as'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a strict sense, "equally as acceptable" should be short for "equally as acceptable *as that other thing just mentioned or compared*".

<s>*Citation needed* I'm aware (but I might get around to expanding later, leaving this as a starting point for now)</s>  *not any longer, read on*

On the other hand, [the M-W quote](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equally%20as) mentioned by @sykkor in the comments make the "equally" serve in a position to additionally stress the equality

> One project is equally as important as the other.

although expressing that equality would be fully conveyed by the equalizing element in the comparison *as ... as* alone. So it's rather a tautology, tempting to say this may be leaving correctness to a matter of taste.

An that's exactly what [the other quote, on BTB](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_e&page=91iP01J6Pj8I.html) says, *(formatting added)*

> ***Equally as* is non-standard English because** the preposition *as* is **unnecessary** after the adverb *equally*.

So here we have the answer to the issue with correctness -- saying *equally as* is **semantically redundant** and **grammatically incorrect**.

This is further supported by the fact that the page on the subject on M-W leads nowhere conclusive, much unlike any M-W page on established language fact. It just fades out, after giving no solid explanation or backing for anything, with the question

> What made you want to look up equally as? Please tell us where you read or heard it (including the quote, if possible).

That's revealing as it rounds up the impression that there's really nothing to state on that page (except online clickbait).

If you feel a need to add stress to an equal comparison in a standard colloquial way, you could say *just as*, but certainly not *as equally as*.

Comment: There are indeed good reasons for regarding *as* as redundant, but it is not clear what the argument is for *equally as* being **grammatically** incorrect.

Comment: thinking aloud, you may be on to something here... thinking about it...